# Let $d$ be a metric on any non empty set $X$ then prove or give counter example of the following: $d_1(x,y) = d^n(x,y)$ where $n \in \Bbb R$

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $d$ be a metric on any non empty set $X$ then prove or give counter example of the following:

$d_1(x,y) = d^n(x,y)$ where $n \in \Bbb R$ is a metric.

My Attempt:
I know that $d_1$ is a metric for $n \in \Bbb N$ and $n = \frac {1}{2}$
I think that $d_1(x,y) = d^n$ is a metric for $n \geq 0$ and it is not a metric for $n < 0$ it is because for negative value of $n$ , $d$ will be of the form $d_1(x,y) = \frac{1}{d(x,y)}$ and $d$ should be non zero.

Comment: What does $d_1$ mean?  Also, $n$ is an unusual choice for a real variable.  Are you sure you didn't mean $n\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: $d_1$ mean metric on $X$. I'm sure $n \in \Bbb R$

Comment: As you say if $n<0$ $d_1$ isn't even a well defined function.

Comment: $d_n(x,y) = ( d(x,y))^n$ ?

Comment: Hint: try a metric on a metric space with points $x, y, z$, such that $d(x, y) + d(y, z) = d(x, z) = 1$. What happens when we take powers of $n > 1$?

Answer (score 3):

For $n<0$ it is not well defined.

For $n = 0$, it is clearly not a metric and for $n = 1$ it clearly is.

If $n \in (0, 1)$, it is indeed a metric. Symmetry and "$d(x, x) =0 \iff x=0$" are obvious. We know that in this case we have for $a, b \in (0, \infty)$:
$$
(a+b)^n \leq a^n+b^n.
$$
To prove this, observe that $g:(0, \infty)^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x, y) := (x+y)^n - x^n - y^n$ is decreasing in $x$ and $y$, i.e. $\partial_x g \leq 0$ and $\partial_y g \leq 0$.

The above gives us the triangle inequality if we do the following ($x, y, z \in X$):
$$
d(x, z)^n \leq (d(x, y) + d(y, z))^n \leq d(x, y)^n + d(y, z)^n
$$

If $n>1$ we simply can not be sure. Let $X := \mathbb{R}$ and $d:X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be the discrete metric
$$
d(x, y) := 
\begin{cases}
1 &, \text{ if } x \neq y \\
0 &, \text{ else}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $d^n = d$ is still a metric. But if we choose $d(x, y) := \lvert x - y \rvert$, then $d^n$ is not a metric. Note that
$$
d^n(x,z) > d^n(x, y) + d^n(y, z)
$$
for $x=\frac{5}{4}$, $z = 0$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}$. So the triangle inequality is violated.

Comment: Here I'm confusing with the case that you have taken. I think that you have taken "Case (i) for $n < 0$, it is not well defined. Case (ii) for $n = 0$, $d$ is not a metric. Case (iii) for $n \in (0,1)$ $d$ is a metric. Case (iv) for $n = 1$ $d$ is a metric. Case(v) for $n \in (1,\infty)$ $d$ is not a metric." I think, last cases overlapped. Please make cases as I said.

Comment: Case (v) is in general not a metric. But it can be, that is what I said. You just can not a priori assume that it is. There are instances of $d$ where it is and where it is not.